# Android play video on surfaceview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, surfaceview, exoplayer

I'm trying to play video with exoplayer in card with a recyclerview. It works well except that when I scroll back to top direction I only have black elements on my surfaceview.

Any Idea?

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: did  you got any solution ? I am facing the same problem.